# How does C manage stack with pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

So I was messing up with dynamic memory and pointers, and I was wondering how C was managing the stack when it comes to pointers that points to local variables.
I came out with this simple function :

```
int* dummy(){
  int test = 4;
  int *t2;
  t2 = &test;
  return t2;
}
```

This function initialize a pointer, and an int as a local variable (should not be accessible outside of my function, as the stack state will be restored once I get out of the function). However, I am returning the pointer as the result of my function.
I can get the pointer back and print the value of my local variable with :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
   int* p = dummy();
// some other calls to other functions to mess up the bellow stack, 
// where my local variable "test" was supposed to be landing
   printf("%d\n", *p); // printing the value of "test" (which is 4)
}
```

**Result**

```
$ ./a.out
4
```

Why is this printing the correct result? Isn't the pointer pointing at a variable in a stack from an other state? I am confused.

If the memory stays somewhere without dynamic allocation, where does it stay? Is it lost forever? (no way to "free" it)

### EDIT after the comments

The behavior is undefined. Adding compiler options for warning such as `pedantic` will print a warning that I am returning a pointer pointing at a local variable, and the executable gets bugus.

The reason for this is that dummy's stack state get lost when the program exists the function, thus not assuring the value of local variables, because they are... local.

Comment: While technically undefined behavior, it just "happens to work" because the stack address still exists.  Call some other function in between `dummy` and `printf`, and the stack memory gets overwritten with values of local variables of the other function.

Comment: Try adding `int x, y, z = 1, 2, 3` after the call.

Comment: @selbie that is what I have been trying. Maybe not enough for overriding the variable.

Comment: Basically, `int test = 4;` puts 4 in some memory location or register or something.  Then you return from the function and the compiler forgets about it.  Then you access that location and it still by coincidence contains the value 4 because the compiler didn't see any reason to spend clock cycles to delete it.  It's a complete coincidence that the value is still there - if you had run other code between running the function and using the return value anything could have happened (the computer could even catch on fire - I'm serious about that)

Comment: Also, just compiling this code with `-O2` will also make it print a completely different value.

Comment: @tadman No effect

Comment: @selbie compiling with -O2 did print me a warning telling me that I am returning a pointer pointing at a local variable, and made the whole thing bugus. That is what I was looking for, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Qwark Strange. Optimization level should not affect warnings. That warning should be emitted irregardless.

Comment: @klutt: Optimization affects warning levels because without optimization the compiler does not do the tracing to know what `t2` holds when it returns and so does not have the information needed to know that a warning should be issued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible outcomes of undefined behavior is - behaving as expected.

Once `dummy` returns, `test` no longer exists - *logically* speaking.  However, the region of the stack it occupied may not be immediately overwritten, so that value may persist in that (virtual) location for some time afterwards.

The pointer is invalid - we’re using it to access an object outside of that object’s lifetime - so the behavior is definitely undefined.  But that doesn’t mean that the value must be something other than `4`.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined behavior is undefined. There is no value this program can print that is, in any sense, "correct". What's confusing you is that you think there is some "correct" value this program can print and therefore you wonder why it's printing the "correct" value.

The problem is entirely in your incorrect understanding that some value is more "correct" than some other value. All values are equally "correct" for this program.

Comment: Well, it prints the value of my test variable. That is what I mean by "correct".

Comment: Just because it does something has absolutely no bearing on it being "correct". Undefined behaviour means it may not work all the time. Since your code has undefined behaviour, it is by definition not correct.

Answer (score -1):

> I was wondering how C was managing the stack when it comes to pointers that points to local variables

It does not. C does not even require a stack. What you are doing is *undefined behavior*  which means that the C standard does not impose ANY requirements on the compiler.

So the answer to your question has nothing to do with the C standard. It can be boiled down to "how it's usually handled". But when you do stuff like it is, as I mentioned, undefined behavior. So this kind of code is likely to be messed up as soon as you turn on any compiler optimizations.

It's possible to make educated guesses about the behavior, but you have no guarantees.

Actually, it's kind of like looking into your neighbours window and be surprised that it's the same neighbour you've had for years. In the exact same way, you have no guarantees that your neighbour has not suddenly moved and someone else have moved in. Well, in your case, this happened. Your neighbour have not moved out yet.